# Différence entre « pourvu que » et « à condition que »

Tags: choix-de-mot, conjonctions

Quelle est la différence entre « pourvu que » et « à condition que » ? Est-ce qu'il y a une différence d'utilisation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ces deux locutions peuvent s'employer indifféremment quand elles introduisent une proposition :

> Je serai à l'heure [pourvu qu](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pourvu_que)'il n'y ait pas de bouchons
>
> Je serai à l'heure [à condition qu](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_condition_que)'il n'y ait pas de bouchons

*Pourvu que* peut aussi introduire et exprimer un souhait : *Pourvu qu'il fasse beau !*, c'est à dire, *j'espère qu'il fera beau !* Dans ce cas, il n'est pas possible d'utiliser *à condition*.

*À condition que* est plus courant que *pourvu que* mais ***si*** sera encore plus courant, d'autant plus qu'il est suivi de l'indicatif :

> Je serai à l'heure **s**'il n'y a pas de bouchons.

Answer (score 2):

« **À condition que** » ; du même sens : à **la** condition que, **sous** (la) condition que ; on utilise le subjonctif, l'indicatif et le conditionnel après ces locutions.  Comme l'indique le substantif qu'elle comprend, cette locution sert à introduire une condition.

Le mode courant utilisé est le subjonctif.

> J'irai à la campagne à condition qu'il ne pleuve pas.
>   Il a dit qu'il ferait ses devoirs de vacance à condition qu'ils ne soient pas trop longs.

« **Pourvu que** » est un synonyme parfait de  « à condition que » tant que son emploi n'est pas au début d'une proposition indépendante ; « à condition que » ne peut alors en aucun cas la remplacer. On doit utiliser le subjonctif dans la proposition qu'elle introduit. Lorsqu'on la trouve au début d'une indépendante elle sert à exprimer un souhait. Aussi bizarre que cela paraisse lorsque cette locution est utilisée en début de phrase elle est encore reconnue comme étant une locution conjonctive.

> (*condition*) Je dormirai dans cette chambre, pourvu que vous y installiez un chauffage.
>   (*souhait*) Pourvu qu'il ne fasse pas trop chaud!

Il n'y a aucune différence entre écrit et oral, ces deux locutions étant d'un registre courant, ni réservées au littéraire ni familières. « À condition que » est plus souvent utilisé, probablement parce que c'est une locution plus parlante ; je crois pouvoir reconnaitre que « pourvu que » se trouvera dans le langage plus recherché des locuteurs dont le niveau d'éducation est au-dessus de la moyenne.

Comment: Est-ce que tous les deux sont employés à l'oral et à l'écrit pour exprimer la condition? Quelle conjonction vous utilisez plus souvent?

Comment: Comme votre question a trait à des détails intéressants que j'ai omis dans ma réponse, j'ajoute ce que peux  dire à leur sujet dans ma réponse, où vous le trouverez.